# Splitting column text

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

I have a fact table that gets updated daily with customer time on app info from a third-party platform that we use, and the identifying number has a bit of text appended to it. So if the customer ID number is 123, this table is getting populated with something like ABC_123. I need to pull this info for a particular cohort of customers based on their ID numbers, so was planning to create a temp table with the customer ID number and the time on app, and drop the appended bit of text. I so far have not had luck finding a way to split the text in that column using the "_" as a delimiter, and I'm hesitant to use a wildcard. Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it would be better to add a `PERSISTED` computed column to the table. Then you have both the original data, and the one you want and you can `INDEX` the `PERSISTED` column too.

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ADD GoodID AS CONVERT(int,STUFF(BadID, 1, CHARINDEX('_',BadID),'')) PERSISTED;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4984377fbd80a46b815d4ac4e3026818)

Comment: Thanks! I don't have edit permission in this part of the database but that gives me what I need to go to the dba and ask them to update that column